# Why are programs suddenly complaining I lack `xterm-kitty` after installing Anaconda? (tput: unknown terminal "xterm-kitty")

Tags: linux, terminal, anaconda

I get this error when running e.g. `vimpager`:

```bash
(base) fred@mapache:~$ echo xidel --xquery `printf "%q" 'let $fonts := //tags/*[name()="DefineFont2"]'$'\n''for $font in $fonts let $oid := $fonts/@objectID/data()'$'\n''let $glyphs := $fonts//Glyph/@map'$'\n''let $fontmaps := <font>'$'\n''<id>{$oid}</id>'$'\n''{for $g in $glyphs let $idx := index-of($glyphs,$g) return (<g idx="{$idx}">{codepoints-to-string($g/data())}</g>, "&#xa;")}</font>'$'\n''let $texts := <t>{for $r in //tags/*[name()="DefineText2"]//* return for $gg in $r//glyphs return <gg>{$gg//TextEntry2//@glyph/data()}</gg>}</t>'$'\n\n''return <root>{$fontmaps}{$texts}</root>'` --input-format=xml --output-format=xml --data=- '<' /tmp/db.xml|vimpager -c 'setf bash'
tput: unknown terminal "xterm-kitty"
tput: unknown terminal "xterm-kitty"
```

Answer (score 0):

This would happen with any uncommon `$TERM`, because Anaconda sets up its own `terminfo` dir:

```bash
(base) fred@mapache:~$ infocmp -D
/home/fred/.miniconda3/share/terminfo
```

You can fix it therefore by copying the terminfo file:

```bash
KITTY=$(find `env -i infocmp -D` -name xterm-kitty) && [ ! -z "$KITTY" ] && cp "$KITTY" "$CONDA_PREFIX/share/terminfo/x/xterm-kitty" || (>&2 echo "Failed to copy!")
```

If you see `Failed to copy!` you need to assure you even have Kitty's terminfo installed.